# Loop infinito en java

Tags: java

tengo un problema con un codigo que debe ordenarme ciertos pedidos de acuerdo a la fecha de entrega mas proxima hasta la mas tardia, el codigo se implementa en una lista, la cual contiene todos los pedidos que se recibieron posterior a la fecha que entrega el usuario y esos son los que se deben reordenar, resulta que al ejecutar el metodo el metodo se recorre sin parar en la linea "while(aux2.getNext()!=null ){" ya que, no se por que se crean infinitos aux2 por lo cual la lista nunca llega a tener null por lo tanto nunca sale del while mencionado, ayudaaaaa

```
 public void OrdenarListaEDD(Date fechaUs){
NodoLista aux=head;
 NodoLista aux2=head.getNext() ; 

      while(aux.getNext()!=null){
          aux2=head.getNext();
          while(aux2.getNext()!=null ){
           if(!aux2.getNext().getDato().getFec_ent().before(aux.getNext().getDato().getFec_ent())){
           } else {
               NodoLista aux3=aux2.getNext();
               aux3.setNext(aux.getNext());
               aux.setNext(aux3);
               aux2.setNext(aux2.getNext().getNext());
              }
           aux2=aux2.getNext();

         }

          aux=aux.getNext();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin analizar si el algoritmo te dará el resultado que buscas, tu error está en que, sin quererlo, creas una lista circular:

A ver si me explico, supongamos que tienes estos nodos en tu lista (utilizo un índice para identificar cada nodo y la notación -> para indicar el índice del siguiente nodo de la lista.

```
1. 1/1/2000 ->2
2. 1/1/2002 ->3
3. 1/1/2001 ->4
4. 1/1/2004
```

Luego de inicializar, quedaríamos así:

```
1. 1/1/2000 -> 2    <- aux
2. 1/1/2002 -> 3    <- aux2
3. 1/1/2001 -> 4
4. 1/1/2004
```

el if

```
if(!aux2.getNext().getDato().getFec_ent().before(aux.getNext().getDato().getFec_ent()))
```

no se cumple y entramos al else:

allí, va ocurriendo esto:

```
           NodoLista aux3=aux2.getNext();

1. 1/1/2000 -> 2    <- aux
2. 1/1/2002 -> 3    <- aux2
3. 1/1/2001 -> 4    <- aux3
4. 1/1/2004

           aux3.setNext(aux.getNext());

1. 1/1/2000 -> 2    <- aux
2. 1/1/2002 -> 3    <- aux2
3. 1/1/2001 -> 2    <- aux3
4. 1/1/2004

           aux.setNext(aux3);

1. 1/1/2000 -> 3    <- aux
2. 1/1/2002 -> 3    <- aux2
3. 1/1/2001 -> 2    <- aux3
4. 1/1/2004

           aux2.setNext(aux2.getNext().getNext());

1. 1/1/2000 -> 3    <- aux
2. 1/1/2002 -> 2    <- aux2
3. 1/1/2001 -> 2    <- aux3
4. 1/1/2004
```

Como ves, ahora, el nodo siguiente del índice 2, es el mismo nodo con índice 2, mientras que ningún nodo guarda relación ya con el nodo índice 4. Tu lógica en principio parece correcta, pero al hacer `.getNext().getNext()` obvias el hecho de que ya previamente has reasignado el siguiente nodo del siguiente nodo.

Puedes, por ejemplo, utilizar otra variable para almacenarlo previamente, cambia el código del else por algo como:

```
           NodoLista aux3=aux2.getNext();
           NodoLista aux4=aux3.getNext();
           aux3.setNext(aux.getNext());
           aux.setNext(aux3);
           aux2.setNext(aux4);
```

Ya con esto no se creará la lista circular, ni se romperá la relación con el nodo siguiente de la lista.

Comment: Siii si ha servido! Pero igualmente no deja de entrar al while, pero ahora del aux, la primera vez que se entra al if queda todo bien, pero despues sigue entrando sin parar al primer while :/

Comment: sebastian, como te dije, no analicé si el algoritmo te daría el resultado, sin embargo, has visto ya cómo he seguido la ejecución paso a paso en este caso. Las herramientas de desarrollo te dan muchas herramientas para evaluar el valor de la variables, ejecutar paso a paso tu programa, etc. Esto, además de poder seguir el algoritmo en papel, ayuda mucho a encontrar los errores lógicos de nuestros programas y corregirlos. Investiga sobre _debug_ (depuración de programas), _breakpoints_, ejecución paso a paso y evaluación de variables.